# problemas con el servidor mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

al crear llaves forneas aunque espesifique las restricciones sea cascade o no action el servidor las almacena Cómo restrict no importa si las creo o las modifico ya sea por workbench o con sentencias sql siempre las almacena como restrict

el siguiente ejemplo crea una llave foranea con la restricon no action. Pero el servidor la guarda con la restriccion restrict.

ejemplo

```
alter table productos add constraint fk_procat foreign key (id_producto) 
references categoria(id_categoria) on delete no action on update no action;
```

o si la restriccion fuese cascade, el servidor la guarda como restrict

```
"on delete cascade on update cascade"
```

alguien podria decirme por que el servidor no reconoce otra restriccion que no sea restrict, o si hay que cambiar algo en la configuración del servidor para que se almacenen las llaves con las demas restricciones

Comment: Solo te pasa con no action y restrict? O as probado realmente a introducir on cascade y ver como te lo almacena?

Comment: habia hecho relaciones con  on cascade y me estaba dando problemas pero no habia observado hasta que cree otras llaves con no action y tambien me estaba dando problemas, entonces utilice workbench para ver las llaves y observe que se almacenaban como restrict , trate de modificarlas y no paso nada, las elimine y cree llaves nuevas con diferentes restricciones y de todas maneras las almacena como restric, mas tarde subire varias imagenes para que las veas

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema, ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7da1cb7bc8dff11106cc7ae7796f0317).

Comment: gracias por la ayuda, aun no se por que es el problema, pero cree otra base de datos y puedo trabajar en ella sin los problemas de la otra